# Repeat script until conditions are met

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with a timer set for 5am and everyday I want the sheet to:

1. Refresh, which includes some links to external data, so I add a 10 second pause. There are approximately 100 rows.
2. I successfully wrote a formula in column U to tell me if data is imported correctly, and if not it returns the text "ERROR".
3. Search for "ERROR" in column U.
4. If there are any "ERRORS" in column U, refresh the page again and wait 10 seconds.
5. Repeat until there are no "ERRORS"
6. Only when there are no "ERRORS" in column U, copy the values in column V and paste-values in column W.

I think I am close... I just can't figure out how to tell it to re-run the "IF" portion if still finds "ERRORS". Any input is appreciated!

Here is a link to the file -> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GFN3tXRlqxo9J9iNpZMPk-e-WlNGVjJ4zSqZ1_aEE_U

```
function HardKeyValues() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Players'), true);
  
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(10000);
  
  var findVal = spreadsheet.getRange('U:U').getValue()
  if(findVal.match('ERROR')){
  
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(10000)}
  
  else{
  spreadsheet.getRange('W:W').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('V:V').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What do you mean by "which includes some links to external data"? By the way, the script have errors i.e.`var findVal = spreadsheet.getRange('U:U').getValue()` always will assign the value of U1 to `findVal`.

Comment: thanks @Rubén in each row, there is a formula in column U that is looking up a value from a website. If there is an error or the website is loading, the result is the cell on that row and column U will return "ERROR". I want the formula to search for any cell in column U that returns "ERROR" and keep refreshing the page until there are none. Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it's not clear. What function are you using retrieving the value from the website? P.S. If you have to use a script it's very likely that it will be a lot better to do the whole job on the script.

Answer (score 1):

#### I would not actually use the sleep timer this way

But if I did I would write it like this:

```
function HardKeyValues() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const psh = ss.getSheetByName('Players');
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(10000);
  const vs = psh.getRange('U1:U' + psh.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().flat();
  if (vs.find(e => e.includes("ERROR"))) {
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
  } else {
    sh.getRange("V1:V" + sh.getLastRow()).copyTo(sh.getRange("W1:W" + sh.getLastRow(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false));
  }
}
```

Using indeterminate ranges like "W:W" often leads to many nulls at the end of the array.

Comment: thank you @cooper do you have an alternate suggestion for sleep? I'm trying to allow the web links a moment to refresh before checking again. I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: The reality is that I almost never use cell functions so I would probably do what I required in a script

Answer (score 0):

What about using a while loop ?

```js
function HardKeyValues() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Players'), true);
  
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(10000);
  
  var findVal = spreadsheet.getRange('U:U').getValue()
  
  while (findVal.match('ERROR')){
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(10000)}
    findVal = spreadsheet.getRange('U:U').getValue()
  }
  
  spreadsheet.getRange('W:W').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('V:V').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

Comment: The original script has errors i.e.`var findVal = spreadsheet.getRange('U:U').getValue()` always will assign the value of U1 to `findVal`.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try using a for loop, just make sure to have a variable that can eventually meet the requirement for the for loop to stop, otherwise, it will turn into a forever loop ;)

Comment: This is basically covered in other answers with code examples